string_split with cast as int and cross apply
I have a stored procedure which outputs ResultTable with column string_data whose row contains a string like - row1: 1,2,3,4 ; row2: 2,3,4,5 and so on. I want to use the string_split inbuilt function to split the rows of the column and have each value as an int using cross apply.
I tried:
declare @TempTable table (SplitInt int)
exec dbo.ProcName
insert into @TempTable

select *, cast(item as int)
from @TempTable
cross apply string_split(string_data, ',')


So what, exactly, is the problem..? (Apart from your design.)

Why are do you INSERT data from @TempTable into @TempTable? I assume that isn't what you want. Considering you don't INSERT anything into that variable prior to that INSERT what are you expecting to be INSERTed?

@ThomA I believe that OP is expecting the output of the stored procedure to be dumped into the temp table.

Then they need to INSERT that data, @shawnt00 ; they don't and they don't explain that's the problem.

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

you have to insert the raw rows first: INSERT INTO @table (row) EXEC ProcName and then do the splitting later. Of course, you could also redesign your procedure. In my humble opinion, it's always better if the procedure populates some table instead of using INSERT / EXEC pattern, because INSERT / EXEC cannot be nested among other issues. Of course, you'll probably write that you can't change the procedure, but anyway

There are several things wrong with your code.

It looks like you intended to capture the dbo.ProcName into @TempTable, but your statement order is wrong (as siggemannen pointed out above).
You define @TempTable with a column SplitInt int, but the later query expects a string named string_data.
The string_split() function returns a column named value, not item.

I've rewritten you code to correct these issues, which should give you something you can expand on.
declare @TempTable table (string_data varchar(max))

insert into @TempTable
exec dbo.ProcName

select *, cast(s.value as int) as SplitInt
from @TempTable t
cross apply string_split(t.string_data, ',') s

If dbo.ProcName returns results having more than one column, you will need to define those columns to @TempTable, so the receiving table definition matches those results.
Results:



string_data
value
SplitInt




1,2,3,4
1
1


1,2,3,4
2
2


1,2,3,4
3
3


1,2,3,4
4
4


2,3,4,5
2
2


2,3,4,5
3
3


2,3,4,5
4
4


2,3,4,5
5
5



Note that value in the results above is a string, while SplitInt is an integer.
See this db<>fiddle.
